# EasyTag and freedb

Tags: cd, multimedia

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10 and I'm using the **EasyTag** program for processing the ID tags on CDs.  It has a facility for looking up CD information online, but it can't get started because the URL for **freedb.freedb.org** cannot be  resolved.  I know there are controversial issues surrounding the CDDB database, but its the online lookup of CD information effectivelly disabled?

Update 1: Going to Edit/Preferences/CDDB leads to what I believe are the necessary settings. But once I got there I was confronted with a deluge of exotica, such as the CGI path and the correct port number, which might be either  80 or 8880.

Answer (score 2):

Does EasyTag let you change the location of the FreeDB lookup service? If so, you may be able to change it to:

```
gnudb.gnudb.org
```

All-round good fellow Andrew.46 has even provided a helpful screenshot showing how these values can be applied:

[image: EasyTag Preferences | CDDB]

Further configuration details can be found on [the GnuDB How To](https://gnudb.org/howto.php) page

Comment: The GnuDB Howto does not include instructions for EasyTag, and it isn't obvious how to apply these instructions to EasyTag.   I found the settings for Automatic and Manual search servers, but it was not obvious how to fill them in.

Comment: Doesn't work. Entering these data results in the error message: "The server returned a negative reply HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" when I try to look up anything.

Comment: @Tilman you may want to let GnuDB.org know, as [their documentation continues to show the values above as being correct](https://gnudb.org/howto.php). If you are receiving a 301, then the server should also be letting you know the new location of the API. You can update your application(s) to use that new location. Otherwise, the GnuDB team will need to be notified as there will be thousands of people with the same problem.

Comment: The GnuDB How To is seriously inconsistent. For all programs *except* EasyTag they emphasize that a unique E-mail address must be used, but for EasyTag they do not even tell how to enter an E-mail address at all, which I suspect is the root of the problem. Regrettably, I do not know how to provoke the 301 manually so that I might see the new location. Equally regrettably, I found no way to notify the GnuDB team of all this.